# Why is the input reflection signal very weak?

Tags: pcb, filter, band-pass

I built a PCB filter in Class "Band-pass" with center frequency of 2.4 GHz. The board has two SMA's (input [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOaFg.jpg) & output [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJMKQ.jpg)).

S(1,2) looks like this:

[image]

The frequency is good, However, the attenuation is bad. My problem is that my Reflection signal S(1,1) looks like:

(I thought I would see a valley going down at the 2.4 GHz frequency)

[image]

(Note: I am using a transmission line design)

The PCB Circuit:

[image]

Specifications:
Filter Type:    Chebychev bandpass
Ripple:  0.5 dB
Ctr. Freq.: 2.437 GHz
Att.:       50 dB @ 2.459 GHz
Tgt. BW:    20 MHz

Substrate:  Rogers RO4350B
εr :    3.48 +/- 0.005
Tsx:    1.524 mm
TCu:    35 μm

Board + Layout:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the datasheet of the device you're testing.

Comment: What is the spacing between the elements of your filter?

Comment: It is a PCB board I designed, should I attach an image of it?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf they range from 1- 6 mm

Comment: Is not input reflection being low an indication of good energy flow into the filter? What is the S21, the energy flow thru the filter?

Comment: yes S21 is thru the filter. and yes I thought the reflection will have a valley (will be lower than the plot)

Comment: Examining the S11, almost **ALL** your energy is reflected. Were that -3dB, then 50% of energy would be absorbed. The S11 plot shows about 1dB (ONE dB), indicating only 25% of the incoming energy has the chance to enter the filter. This is not a proper filter, IMHO.

Comment: The answer is that you've not built a PCB filter, you've built a PCB thing which is almost totally mismatched. If you want help with the design, then you need to post what type of filter you're trying to design, what order, what specs (bandwidth, attenuation depth at what offset), what design program you've used, and a picture of the board.

Comment: @Neil_UK I added them.

Comment: Those look to be humungeous great gaps, what synthesis program came up with those? A gap of 4 or 5 substrate thicknesses is essentially not coupled, unless, perhaps, you have extraordinarly high Q resonators, which you don't have with copper. Are you targetting a very very small bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everybody. I think I solved it. The reason was the wires (cables) resistance was high so it was causing the attenuation. I replaced one of them and I was able to see better spectrum.